# Error exporting RTF BI Publisher template to PDF when I change a table design in Microsoft Word

Tags: java, ms-word, rtf, bi-publisher

I'm designing some .rtf templates to exporting them into PDF format. I made a table in Word with the BIP table wizard and I tried to change the table design with Microsoft Word properties. When I export the template into PDF with a BI Publisher data model behind, Word throws me the following error:

```
oracle.xdo.XDOException at oracle.xdo.template.rtf.RTFParser.generate(RTFParser.java:165)
at oracle.xdo.template.rtf.RTF2XSLParser.generateXSL(RTF2XSLParser.java:343)
```

The template exports correctly when I put the standard design. I'd like to know if it is a problem with my BIP version or something I'm doing wrong in the template.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide the data model, table design that works, and table design that does not work. Also, please explain what you mean by "exporting template into PDF." It sounds like you are just running the .rtf against an .xml file with the template viewer, but just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I'm running the .rtf against a .xml file, and then BIP generates the PDF file. The main problem is when I create a table in Word with BIP utilities and then I try to change the table design. When I run the .rtf the error appears, but I've been seeing that it only happens when I group data by a field in the table wizard. It might be a internal rendering problem.